# Help with factorizing

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

In [this](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra2/x2ec2f6f830c9fb89:exp-model/x2ec2f6f830c9fb89:construct-exp/v/constructing-exponential-models) video (at around 1:20) Sal does the following: $$40 + \frac{9}{10} \cdot 40 = 40(1 + \frac{9}{10}) = 40 \cdot 1.9$$

I can't figure out that first part where he goes from $$40 + \frac{9}{10} \cdot 40$$ to $$40(1 + \frac{9}{10})$$

I thought he was factoring out a $40$ from $40 + \frac{9}{10}$ but to my knowledge he's supposed to divide both numbers on either side of the $+$ sign if he was factoring, is that not so? Which would make it:

$$40(1+\frac{\frac{9}{10}}{40})$$

What am I missing here? Is he even factoring or is it something else entirely?

Comment: Note that the expression $40+\frac9{10}.40$ is equivalent to $40+(\frac9{10}.40)$. Now factor out $40$.

Comment: This is just $a+a\cdot b = a\cdot (1+b)$ with the specific values of $a$ and $b$ being $40$ and $\frac{9}{10}$ respectively.  "*I thought he was factoring a $40$ from $40+\frac{9}{10}$ but...*"  No, he was factoring a $40$ from $40+\frac{9}{10}\cdot 40$, that is not the same thing.  Note that $\frac{\frac{9}{10}\cdot 40}{40}$ is the same thing as $\frac{9}{10}$

Comment: @JMoravitz okay cool, I hear what you're saying but I'm like a next level math noob and it's not computing in my brain lol. Is there a name for that $a + a \cdot b = a(1 + b)$ pattern? I think if I maybe read up on it some more I might be able to figure it out.

Comment: "Distributivity"

Comment: At this point I'm just chalking it up to "a pattern they never taught us (or that I must've missed)" coz I don't remember ever seeing anything about $a + a \cdot b$ when they taught us the distributive property. It was all $a(b + c) = (a \cdot b) + (a \cdot c)$ and whatnot lol. But anyway, if you wanna put that pattern in an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: $a(1+c)=(a\cdot 1)+(a\cdot c) = (a) + (a\cdot c)$... because multiplying by one doesn't change the number

Comment: You should have seen and know that $3a+4a = 7a$... you should have seen and know that $a+5a = 6a$.  There is no major difference here except that while in $3a+4a$ we might have evaluated $3+4$ while combining to get $7a$ or combining $1$ and $5$ to get $6$... here our coefficients aren't necessarily known numbers like "3" or "4" but can instead be variables which we intentionally keep written as a sum.  $a+ac = a(1+c)$ is no different than $a+5a = a(1+5)$

Answer (score 1):

Note that$$40\left(1+\frac9{10}\right)=40\times1+40\times\frac9{10}=40+\frac9{10}\cdot40.$$

Comment: Okay hold on hold on, I need to go slow here lol. I see what you're saying with that first part $40(1 + \frac{9}{10}) = 40 \times 1 + 40 \times \frac{9}{10}$ , but I don't get the second part where $40 \times 1 + 40 \times \frac{9}{10} = 40 + \frac{9}{10} \cdot 40$ .

Doesn't that violate the order of operations? Nowhere on the left side are we saying $40 + \frac{9}{10}$ so how're you getting that on the right side?

Comment: When we multiply two numbers $a$ and $b$, the order does not matter: $a\times b=b\times a$.

Comment: No I get that, but in first part it's $40 \times 1 + 40 \times \frac{9}{10}$ so that would be $40 + \frac{360}{10}$ coz AFAIK with order of operations you're supposed to multiply first, no? Like with $40 + \frac{9}{10} \cdot 40$ we've now completely jumbled up the numbers and symbols. It feels like we did the equivalent of $5 + 2 - 9 = 5 + 9 - 2$ lol. It's all very confusing.

Comment: But both numbers $40\times\frac9{10}$ and $\frac9{10}\times40$ are equal to $\frac{360}{40}$. So, where's the problem?

Comment: Lol you're absolutely right. I see they both equal the same thing and yet I can't figure it out. It's driving me crazy. I'm just gonna memorize @JMoravitz' $a + a \cdot b = a(1 + b)$ for now, I rate. Thanks for taking the time though.

Comment: Just count apples: $1$ apple and $9/10$ of an apple gives $1 + 9/10$ of an apple.  Now count fourties.